# Unity 2018 Camera to follow object but pan with arrow keys

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am very new with Unity (started a few days ago).

I am trying to create the functionality where the camera will always follow a rolling ball, but the camera should be controlled by the arrow keys as well, while still focusing on the main object.

I have the following code that follows the actual object:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform player;
    private Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, 3, -5);

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        transform.position = player.position + offset;
    }
}
```

The above code works perfect and it follows the object as it moves.

But I tried the following to move the camera around:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform player;
    public GameObject MainCamera;
    public Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, 3, -5);

    private Vector3 RotateOffset;
    public float rotateJump = 1f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {

        //Rotate Camera 90 degrees Left
        if (Input.GetKey("left")) {
            RotateOffset = new Vector3(transform.position.x - rotateJump, 0, transform.position.z - rotateJump);
            transform.position = player.position + RotateOffset;
        }

        //Rotate Camera 90 degrees Right
        if (Input.GetKey("right")) {
            RotateOffset = new Vector3(transform.position.x + rotateJump, 0, transform.position.z + rotateJump);
            transform.position = player.position + RotateOffset;
        }
    }
}
```

But this only moves the camera in a straight line from Position A to B as seen below without rotating:

Position A:
[image]

position B:
[image]

How can I get the camera to follow the object and still be controlled by the user?

Thanks in advance!

---

My code to move the object around the board looks like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float MovementForce = 200f;

    void FixedUpdate() {
        //Move Forward
        if (Input.GetKey("w")) {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, MovementForce * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        //Move Left
        if (Input.GetKey("a")) {
            rb.AddForce(-MovementForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

        //Move Back
        if (Input.GetKey("s")) {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, - MovementForce * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        //Move Right
        if (Input.GetKey("d")) {
            rb.AddForce(MovementForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**

I updated my FollowPlayer script to look like this:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform player;
    private Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, 3, -5);

    private float RotateVal = 2f;

    private Vector3 VPanAmount = new Vector3(2, 0, 0);
    private Vector3 HPanAmount = new Vector3(0, 2, 0);

    private Vector3 VRotatoinOffset;
    private Vector3 HRotatoinOffset;

    private void Start() {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {

        if (Input.GetKey("left")) {
            VRotatoinOffset = player.position + offset - VPanAmount;
            transform.Rotate(0, -RotateVal, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("right")) {
            VRotatoinOffset = player.position + offset + VPanAmount;
            transform.Rotate(0, RotateVal, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("up")) {
            HRotatoinOffset = player.position + offset + HPanAmount;
            transform.Rotate(-RotateVal, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("down")) {
            HRotatoinOffset = player.position + offset + HPanAmount;
            transform.Rotate(RotateVal, 0, 0);
        }

        transform.position = player.position + offset - VRotatoinOffset - HRotatoinOffset;
    }
}
```

The camera rotates and moves as the object moves, but the camera's focus does not stay on the object and the camera jumps to below the playing field.

Comment: I only see code that changes the camera's position, if you want to rotate the camera, you need also change it's rotation.

Comment: but how do I keep the camera a fixed distance away from the object while still rotating? I was able to do them separately, but when I applied rotation, the camera did not follow anymore and rotated in one place

Comment: Please see update with regards to camera rotation

Comment: Transform has a method called RotateAround, you can specify an axis to rotate.